# java.lang.ClassCastException in Arrays.sort call though implementing Comparable

Tags: java, comparable

I am trying to sort an array of Rectangles using `Arrays.sort`. The class `Rectangle` implements `Comparable<Rectangle>` and I have overridden the `compareTo()` method. These are the two classes: Rectangle and the tester class.

```
public class Rectangle implements Comparable<Rectangle> {

  private int length;
  private int width;

  public Rectangle(int length, int width) {
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
  }

  public int getLength() {
    return length;
  }

  public int getWidth() {
    return width;
  }

  public int getPerimeter() {
    return (2*length) + (2*width);
  }

  public int compareTo(Rectangle x) {
    int p2 = ((Rectangle)x).getPerimeter();
    return this.getPerimeter()-p2;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "Perimeter: " + this.getPerimeter();
  }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[4];
  rectangles[0] = new Rectangle(3, 4);
  rectangles[1] = new Rectangle(2, 6);
  rectangles[2] = new Rectangle(2, 2);
  rectangles[3] = new Rectangle(1, 1);

  for (Rectangle x : rectangles) {
    System.out.println(x.getPerimeter());
  }

  Arrays.sort(rectangles);
}
```

However, I keep getting an error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Rectangle cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable.

Can someone help me see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you casting `x` to `Rectangle` in `compareTo(Rectangle x)` when the parameter already states `x` is a `Rectangle`?

Comment: I get the error either way, but I agree, it is unnecessary.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception and are you leaving any other code out? I ran your code through Eclipse and no exceptions were thrown.

Comment: I also cannnot see any problems in this. Are you sure the array you want to sort is of type `Rectangle[]`? Does `Rectangle` have further child classes?

Comment: Full error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Rectangle cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:316)
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:184)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1246)
 at Test.main(Test.java:53)

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Your stack trace says Test.java:53, but Test.java in your post is ~20 lines. I suspect the issue is in code you aren't showing us.

Comment: What is: `java.util.ComparableTimSort`?? Can you show your imports? It looks like you implemented `Comparable`, allowed your IDE to auto-resolve the associated import, and have pulled in something unexpected in the process.

Comment: The rest of the lines were commented out code. Here is the error message w/o comments: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Rectangle cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:316)
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:184)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1246)
 at Test.main(Test.java:17)

Comment: Hi! Your code compiles and runs fine. I will suspect sth is wrong with your building the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Rectangle cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable.
```

Possibly your version of Rectangle that is in main class is not comparable.
    Make sure the class Rectagle you are refering is the one you shown above.

Make sure you build the class correctly. I suggest using an IDE to build you classes and doing a clean build should fix this.